# GRUB does not boot Debian automatically after upgrade

Tags: debian, boot, grub2

I have one server, which I did not use for one month, literally shut down.

The server is running Debian 9.0. I upgraded it from Jessie about two months ago to `testing` repository.

Yesterday I needed it, so I turned it on and upgraded all packages for security reasons.

Before this upgrade: GRUB booted automatically the only OS on this server.

After this upgrade: I must press Enter for it to do so. Therefore I must have keyboard plugged in etc. I am sure you understand the inconvenience.

Also I noticed changed background both on the login screen, and the desktop.

As far as I know, this file:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

is responsible for GRUB's behavior, so I copy-paste it first:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

I did not do any other change. I am unsure whether it upgraded from Stretch to Sid or whatever the naming is. I am also confused as to what could cause this kind of seemingly negligible problem, but I sincerely hope there are folks who understand Debian better than me.

If you need any information I will deliver it on a timely fashion.

**EDIT1:**

```
uname -a
```

output

```
Linux backup-server 4.9.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.2-2 (2017-01-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

output

```
deb http://ftp.sh.cvut.cz/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.sh.cvut.cz/debian/ testing main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I did a regular maintenance, one of which is to do a full upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Among those upgraded, there was a new kernel, and also new GRUB packages installed.

Problem got solved by this. Booting automatically again.